# adding styled-components to project causes. Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

Build a default react-native application, with Typescript and add styled-components, reference it in the app and attempt to compile causes the following error:

node_modules/styled-components/typings/styled-components.d.ts(116,44): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

Please see repo to reproduce.  https://github.com/StevenTCramer/Issue1

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question

Comment: @bennygenel I have a link to GitHub repo with a minimal complete and verifiable example already?

Comment: Did you try installing `@types/node`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need install `@types/node` with npm in order to pick up the NodeJS namespace.

```
$ npm install --save-dev @types/node
```