# Errors in typescript with dynamic import

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

I am getting following error.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/boot.ts:7:23 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/boot.ts:7:29 
    TS1134: Variable declaration expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/boot.ts:8:25 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/boot.ts:8:31 
    TS1134: Variable declaration expected.
```

I have following boot.ts file.

```
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Counter = () => import('./components/counter/counter');
const FetchData = () => import('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata');

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
    { path: '/counter', component: Counter },
    { path: '/fetchdata', component: FetchData }
];

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html'))
});
```

My tsconfig.json file look like below,.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
  ],
    "types": ["webpack-env"]
  },
  "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I want to achieve following. I am using webpack. So if required, I can post here.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using? Dynamic import syntax is not supported before 2.4.

Comment: Sorry. I am very new to this. But my package.json seems like this.
"typescript": "^2.2.1",

Comment: If you run `npm list typescript`, what is the output?

Comment: Hey, man. I tried npm update --save. and now new error. 
 TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

Comment: and your command shows. `-- typescript@2.7.2

Comment: What's the full text of that error message? Where is it occurring? It sounds like you might need to install the types for node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495257/adding-styled-components-to-project-causes-cannot-find-namespace-nodejs

Comment: Regardless, it sounds like that's a separate issue. For future readers, I've added an answer for the Typescript version upgrade as the solution to the dynamic import problem. If you can mark it as correct, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic import syntax is only supported in Typescript in versions 2.4+. The most likely fix is that you need to upgrade your Typescript version.

Use the following to update the version of Typescript:

```
npm update --save-dev typescript
```

Or, if you're using a globally installed version:

```
npm update -g typescript
```

You can run `npm list typescript` (or `npm list -g typescript`) afterwards to make sure it was successful.